# android youtube player OpenYouTubeActivity fullscreen is not working on Android 4.3 and later

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

m using the android youtube player [OpenYouTubeActivity](https://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/), i'm using the svn source code, not the jar file provided in the project. But it seems that this activity is not working after the 4.3 android releases. the video is shown half of the full screen, but everything else works fine. [THis issue is already logged on the issues list on the project site.](https://code.google.com/p/android-youtube-player/issues/detail?id=28)

Anybody has any clue, whats happening? Any solution is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its always best to use the jars, because you get the latest compiled code and its easy for the maintainers to maintain versions. But I think on the code branch the fix here is to decompile the jar using an open source decompiler like http://jd.benow.ca/ and then copy the code as is. 
Then you can see where the changes have been made.

**DISCLAIMER**

Please follow the licensing as the original wants it. I think its as per Apache, so make sure to include appropriate licensing information and credits and follow licensing laws.